# How to deploy a dynamically scalable AI service that run on GPUs in GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently trying to deploy a backend service API (running a tensorflow model in python and flask environment, with GPUs of course) for my app, which needs to be scalable so that I can serve to say maybe 1000 requests simultaneously.

The model needs to run 15 seconds per request, which is relatively slow, and there is a timeout limit for firebaseapp that I need to satisfy for each request. The question is that I want to deploy this thing in google-kubernetes-engine, but I don't know how to deploy my image so that each pod(running an image) is running in only one gpu-node (and vice versa) and each request is directed to one available pod, meaning no two requests are directed to the same pod.

I know there is something called Daemonset https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/daemonset But I'm not sure if this fits my need. Another question is that is it possible to scale pod/gpu-nodes by requests (or by pod availability)? For example, if currently there is only one node running one pod, the first incoming request can be served, and if the second requests come in, then the second pod/gpu-node need to be generated to serve the request. What is the traffic directing mechanism? Is it Ingress Service? How do I detect pod availability in the traffic directing mechanism? To sum up, here are three questions: 1. How to direct each request to each different pod? 2. How to run only one pod in one GPU-Node? 3. How to scale (one unit of Daemonset maybe ?) and scale fast so that each request can be served within 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

1. You may use [Container-native load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing) in order to target pods and evenly distribute traffic.
2. Please have a look at pod [anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity), where the idea is that the pod should not run in node X if that node X is already running one or more pods that meet a rule.
3. For autoscaling, I would go with [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) (horizontal pod autoscaler), so pods will scale depending on the metric that is being monitored.

Comment: I successfully used pod anti-affinity to deploy pods so that one node only run one pod, thank you for that.

Comment: But for the traffic directing, it seems that the OPTIONS preflight request and POST request goes to different pods. It also seems that one container receives multiple requests at almost the same time. One pod might receives two OPTIONS preflight requests, while the other pod might receives two POST requests. How can I set something so that the OPTIONS request and POST request can be sent to the same pod (as an atomic operation, rather than two different requests sent to two different pods), and a pod can notify the load balancer that it is not available when it received that atomic request  ?

Comment: Or should I say: Is there a way so that the load balancer knows not to schedule two (OPTIONS then POST pair) requests to the same pod at almost the same time, unless it know the first (OPTIONS then POST pair) request is complete ? On the assumption that the OPTIONS and the POST can be sent to the same pod, of course, but how to do that also ?

Comment: When using load balancer, traffic will travel to the node instance group and gets routed via iptables rules to pods, however pods might not be on the same node. With container-native load balancing, you are skipping one hop and ensuring a more even distribution of traffic to your pods and targeting your required pods.